# Where are the AVP Scenario definition and parameters?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Autoware.Auto course [lectures](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/autowareclass2020/-/blob/master/lectures/01_DevelopmentEnvironment/devenv2.md) have referenced this document https://discourse.ros.org/uploads/short-url/yc1H3yPx3yw0QhH25NZYEAG6Xul.pdf for describing the ODD design process of Autoware.Auto.

On pages 3 and 4 of this document it is described how the ODD is broken down into scenarios and parameters. I don't see such a definition for the AVP ODD anywhere in the Autoware.Auto documentation. Does it exist and if so where?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355044/where-are-the-avp-scenario-definition-and-parameters?/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2020-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't exist. That document has "Draft" stamped on every page because that's what it is: a draft of a proposed process that has not yet been put into practice.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2020-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-06-16**:
That being said, the ODD Working Group will be formed during the next Technical Steering Committee call so we are beginning to implement this process. The first task for the new ODD WG will be to fully define the AVP ODD.